# Reading TXT Record in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa, networking, cfnetwork

I'm slowly learning to code for networks and have come to a bit of a dead end: I thought that by accessing the TXT Record of a nas drive I'd be able to see the volumes it offered as described at:

http://files.dns-sd.org/draft-cheshire-dnsext-dns-sd.txt

But when I run this code:

```
browse = [[NSNetServiceBrowser alloc]init];
[browse setDelegate:self];
[browse searchForServicesOfType:@"_afpovertcp._tcp." inDomain:@"local"];
```

To set up a search for sevices and the following for the callback:

```
-(void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser didFindService:(NSNetService *)aNetService moreComing:(BOOL)moreComing
{
    NSLog(@"Found: %@",aNetService);
    CFNetServiceRef aCFNetRef;
    aCFNetRef = CFNetServiceCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)[aNetService domain],(__bridge CFStringRef) [aNetService type], (__bridge CFStringRef)[aNetService name], 0);
    CFStreamError error;
    if (CFNetServiceResolveWithTimeout(aCFNetRef, timeOut, &error)) {
        NSLog(@"CFNET TXT: %@",CFNetServiceGetTXTData(aCFNetRef));
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"TXTRecord: %@",[NSNetService dictionaryFromTXTRecordData:[aNetService TXTRecordData]]);       
    if (!moreComing) {
        [browse stop];
        [refreshButton setEnabled:YES];
        [self reloadInputViews];
    }
}
```

The `nslog()` lines show that the TXT Record of the found service is empty: I get something along the lines of

```
Found: <NSNetService 0x6a90fd0> local. _afpovertcp._tcp. myLocalSVR
CFNET TXT: <00>
TXTRecord: (null)
```

Can someone say whether I've got the code right or is it just that the local nas here doesn't containt a TXT Record - from what I've read, though, this just shouldn't be the case. I've also read that the service needs to be resolved before a TXT Record is coughed up, but I was hoping that that's what the `CFNetServiceResolveWithTimeout()` is doing...

Thanks!

Todd.

Comment: Have you checked that the NAS is announcing itself via mDNS? You can do an equivalent query from the Terminal to the one you are trying with the command: dns-sd -B _afpovertcp._tcp local

Answer (score 1):

From the document you link to (http://files.dns-sd.org/draft-cheshire-dnsext-dns-sd.txt), emphasis mine:

> The intention of DNS-SD TXT records is to convey a small amount of 
>   useful additional information about a service. Ideally it should not
>   be necessary for a client to retrieve this additional information
>   before it can usefully establish a connection to the service. **For a 
>   well-designed application protocol, even if there is no information
>
>   at all in the TXT record, it should be possible, knowing only the
>
>   host name, port number, and protocol being used, to communicate with
>
>   that listening process, and then perform version- or feature-
>
>   negotiation to determine any further options or capabilities of the
>
>   service instance**. For example, when connecting to an Apple Filing
>   Protocol (AFP) [AFP] server over TCP, the client enters into a
>   protocol exchange with the server to determine which version of AFP
>   the server implements, and which optional features or capabilities
>   (if any) are available.

I understand that the proper thing to do is establish an AFP session with the discovered server to list the shares.

You can check the TXT records of the NAS with `dns-sd -L`:

> `dns-sd -L name type domain`
>   look up and display the information necessary to contact and use the named service: the hostname of the machine where that service is available, the port number on which the
>   service is listening, **and (if present) TXT record** attributes describing properties of the service.

Doing an _afpovertcp query on my local network I get:

```
$ dns-sd -L mir _afpovertcp._tcp. local.
Lookup mir._afpovertcp._tcp..local.
 1:14:40.948  mir._afpovertcp._tcp.local. can be reached at mir.local.:548 (interface 4) Flags: 1
 1:14:40.948  mir._afpovertcp._tcp.local. can be reached at mir.local.:548 (interface 5) Flags: 1
 1:14:40.948  mir._afpovertcp._tcp.local. can be reached at mir.local.:548 (interface 9) Flags: 1
 1:14:40.948  mir._afpovertcp._tcp.local. can be reached at mir.local.:548 (interface 10) Flags: 1
 1:14:40.948  mir._afpovertcp._tcp.local. can be reached at mir.local.:548 (interface 11) Flags: 1
 1:14:40.948  mir._afpovertcp._tcp.local. can be reached at mir.local.:548 (interface 12)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks itorres. It does a similar thing in my terminal window. Your post certainly helps me understand the underlying mechanics. I need to continue my search into how to connect and interact with a service. I think I was too optimistic to hope for a nice obj-c library that would let me connect and interrogate services! It's going to be more of an uphill struggle I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but just worked this out myself.

The TXTRecordData is not available until the netServiceDidResolveAddress is called.
Eg:

```
- (void)netServiceDidResolveAddress:(NSNetService *)service {

    NSData* data = [service TXTRecordData];
    NSDictionary* dict = [NSNetService dictionaryFromTXTRecordData:data];
```

You are checking at the didFindService point but any calls before the address is resolved will return nil.

Comment: Thanks Matt. It is old but I didn't get anywhere with it so would be good to resurrect the project.

Comment: So I obtained a result with - (void)netServiceDidResolveAddress:(NSNetService *)sender but it's still not clear how I go about interrogating for available features on the remote machine. The TXT record is still shown as "<00>".

Comment: So, when you fill the dictionary in netServiceDidResolveAddress like I added above, you get "<00>" in your dictionary? Or an empty dictionary? In my case, for AirPrint, I get 25 or so entries in my dictionary.